# distribution of Poisson random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

If I have a sample $X = (X_1,...,X_n)$ with Poisson distribution, and I have $Y = n\cdot X_{1:n}$ it has the same distribution with the same parameters or I have to change something?

Comment: Do you mean that each $X_i$,$i=1,\ldots,n$ follows a Poisson distribution?

Comment: Yes, each one has Poisson distribution

Comment: What do you mean by $X_{1:n}$? In general, it is a good idea to define any notation that is not standard.